# machine parsable method of comparing the current branch to the local view of the tracking branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-status

I need a machine parsable way of comparing the current branch to the local copy of the tracking branch.

These are the ideas I've tried, with their caveats:

- git status:  not guaranteed to stay the same between different versions of git
- git status --porcelain: doesn't output the required information
- compare head of branch to head of origin/branch: Can we guarantee that the tracking branch is on "origin"?

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: You can use `git diff --name-status` or `git diff --name-only` to get some fairly machine parseable output.  I don't really understand your 3rd question though, about having a guarantee that the tracking branch is on origin.  Can you explain that more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the command you are looking for is:

```
git rev-list HEAD..HEAD@{u}
```

This will list all commit SHAs that are on the tracking branch but not your local branch. `rev-list` is simply command for listing revisions and the `@{u}` on a branch name means “the remote tracking-branch of this branch”.

Comment: Very helpful, just adding, that for current version: git rev-list HEAD -1 can be used